# Double entries in dataframe after merg r

Tags: r, merge

[My data](https://uni-bonn.sciebo.de/s/83m8bBMOIGcrk8k)

Hello, I have a problem with merging two dataframes with each other.

The goal is to merge them so that each date has the corresponding values. If there is no corresponding value, I want to replace NA with 0.

```
names(FiresNearLA.ab.03)[1] <- "Date.Local"

U.NO2.ab.03 <- unique(NO2.ab.03) # No2.ab.03 has all values multiplied

ind <- merge(FiresNearLA.ab.03,U.NO2.ab.03,  all = TRUE, all.x=TRUE) 

ind[is.na(ind)] <- 0
```

So far so good. And the first lines look like they are supposed to look. But beginning from 2004-04-24, all dates are doubled and it writes weird values in the second NO2.Mean colum.

```
U.NO2.Mean table:

        Date.Local  NO2.Mean
361   2004-03-31 30.217391
365   2004-04-24 50.000000
366   2004-04-25 47.304348
370   2004-04-26 50.913043
374   2004-04-27 41.157895

ind table:

     Date.Local FIRE_SIZE F.number.n_fires  NO2.Mean
113  2004-04-22     34.30               10 13.681818
114  2004-04-23     45.00               13 17.222222
115  2004-04-24     55.40               22 28.818182
116  2004-04-24     55.40               22 50.000000
117  2004-04-25   2306.85               15 47.304348
118  2004-04-25   2306.85               15 21.090909
```

Why, are there Values in NO2.Mean for 2004-04-23 and 2004-04-22 days if they should be 0? and why does it double the values after the 24th and where do the second ones come from?

Thank you

Comment: Trying to load your file I get the error: `bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘FiresNearLA.ab.03.RData’ has magic number 'X'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated `. Could you use dput instead to share a small sample?

Comment: Your merge command also doesn't look correct to me. Look in `?merge.data.frame`. You are missing a `by` argument and either `all` or `all.x` are unnecessary.

Comment: Ok. uploaded it as dput txt now. `merge(FiresNearLA.ab.03,U.NO2.ab.03, by="Date.Local", all = TRUE)` , sadly doesnt change the problem. PS. Iḿ pretty new to R. So Iḿ sorry for noobing around here

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to merge your data:

```
FiresNearLA.ab.03 <- dget("FiresNearLA.ab.03.txt", keep.source = FALSE)
U.NO2.ab.03 <- dget("NO2.ab.03.txt", keep.source = FALSE)

ind <- merge(FiresNearLA.ab.03, 
             U.NO2.ab.03,  
             all = TRUE,
             by.x = "DISCOVERY_DATEymd",
             by.y = "Date.Local")
```

As a side note: Usually, you share a small sample of your data on stackoverflow, not the whole thing. In your case, `dput(FiresNearLA.ab.03[1:50, ])` and then copy and paste from the console to the question would have been sufficient.

Back to your problem: The duplication already happens in `NO2.ab.03` and a number of dates and values occurs twice or more often. The easiest way to solve this (in my experience) is to use the package `data.table` which has a `duplicated` which is more straightforward and also faster:

```
library(data.table)
# Test duplicated occurrences in U.NO2.ab.03
> table(duplicated(U.NO2.ab.03, by = c("DISCOVERY_DATEymd", "NO2.Mean")))

FALSE  TRUE 
 7767 27308 
> 
> nrow(ind)
[1] 35229
# Remove duplicated rows from data frame
> ind <- ind[!duplicated(ind, by = c("DISCOVERY_DATEymd", "NO2.Mean")), ]
> nrow(ind)
[1] 7921
```

After these steps, you should be fine :)

Comment: Sadly the problem persists. I tried to make a small sample of the data, but weirdly I cant re-creat the problem with the small sample. The !duplicate seems to delete some double rows but after the  `2004-04-24`, it puts double values in the dates and weird values in NO2.mean. Before that date everything is as it should be. I tried to use !duplicate on NO2.ab.03 before merging too, but it doesnt help.

Comment: I just upladed a sample file of the "problem" list.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. As I mentioned above, the duplication is not a problem that results from the merge function but is in your U.NO2.ab.03. Values are also not changed during the merging. If you think the values are weird, you have to check your original data source. Possibly ask a new question about it where you explaine where the data comes from and why you think it's weird.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. The Original data source of `NO3.ab.03` was faulty. 
As `JonGrub` suggestes said, the problem was within `NO3.ab.O3`. For some days it had two different `NO3.Means` corresponding to the same date. I deleted this rows and now its working good. Thank you again for the help and the great advices